# Install Linux Mint on Encrypted WIN7 SSD?

Tags: encryption, linux-mint

Is it possible to install Linux Mint on top of a preexisting win7 os.

Basically I want to put mint install on usb. Change boot to the usb and then format/wipe the entire windows partition during the mint install.

Will I have problems doing that being the ssd is encrypted with checkpoint?

Comment: You do know that a Mint live iso (the one you download from their site) on a DVD or a USB is bootable; you don't need to do a full install onto the USB first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wipe and reformat any disk you want. Make sure that all the data you need is backed up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/517224)

Comment: He wants to wipe the entire disk. Checkpoint is a software encryption tool. Wiping the disk will remove the encryption, so it should not be a problem, just like I said.

Comment: I don't attempt to defend system generated comments.  The comment was submitted because I believe your answer to be a comment.  Its not detailed enough in my opinion.  I wish they were not generated automatically honestly.

Comment: The question doesn't really warrant an answer more than "No you shouldn't have problems, just do it"...

Comment: Thank you SPRBRN. You have answered my question effectively. I should have described my question better I do know you don't have to do a full install on the usb. Xen2050 you may know more than me but your not that respectful as others, just my opinion.